# How to get all posts with one category on one page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress. I have make a template for post. But I don't know how to get the all posts with one category on one page in wordpress. Can anyone please help me to sort out this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code.
you can add category id and post per page as you want.

```
 <?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=10' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<ul>
<li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

<ul><li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Code is running Fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
// The Query
query_posts( array(
      'category_name'  => 'my-category-slug',
      'posts_per_page' => -1
) ); 

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
        the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```